# The example-runtime-bundle by Activiti cloud application don't work. Activiti cloud 7.1.0-M8

Tags: java, activiti

I try to start the example-runtime-bundleexapmple (https://github.com/Activiti/activiti-cloud-application.git) but the project dont't start.

The "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A default binder has been requested error, but there is no binder available" error is appeared and the application is crashed.
Anybody did run this project ? How can i run this project?

> > :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.2.8.RELEASE) :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.2.8.RELEASE)
>
> 2020-08-15 10:58:08.685  INFO [,,,] 91864 --- [           main]
> o.a.c.runtime.RuntimeBundleApplication   : No active profile set,
> falling back to default profiles: default 2020-08-15 10:58:09.293
> INFO [,,,] 91864 --- [           main]
> o.s.c.a.ConfigurationClassParser         : Properties location
> [classpath:/activiti-audit-producer.properties] not resolvable: class
> path resource [activiti-audit-producer.properties] cannot be opened
> because it does not exist 2020-08-15 10:58:10.784  INFO [,,,] 91864
> --- [           main] o.s.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope     : BeanFactory id=28b2cb7c-0c5f-3fb9-a7a6-b942747f204a 2020-08-15
> 10:58:10.885  INFO [,,,] 91864 --- [           main]
> faultConfiguringBeanFactoryPostProcessor : No bean named
> 'errorChannel' has been explicitly defined. Therefore, a default
> PublishSubscribeChannel will be created. 2020-08-15 10:58:10.892  INFO
> [,,,] 91864 --- [           main]
> faultConfiguringBeanFactoryPostProcessor : No bean named
> 'taskScheduler' has been explicitly defined. Therefore, a default
> ThreadPoolTaskScheduler will be created.
>
> ........... ......... .........
>
> > .ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'outputBindingLifecycle'; nested exception is
> > java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A default binder has been
> > requested, but there is no binder available 2020-08-15 10:58:26.091
> > WARN [,,,] 91864 --- [           main]
> > o.s.b.f.support.DisposableBeanAdapter    : Invocation of destroy
> > method failed on bean with name 'tomcatMetricsBinder':
> > java.lang.NullPointerException 2020-08-15 10:58:26.106  INFO [,,,]
> > 91864 --- [           main] o.s.s.c.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler          :
> > Shutting down ExecutorService 'taskScheduler' 2020-08-15 10:58:26.107
> > INFO [,,,] 91864 --- [           main]
> > o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down
> > ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor' 2020-08-15 10:58:26.108
> > INFO [,,,] 91864 --- [           main]
> > com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown
> > initiated... 2020-08-15 10:58:26.115  INFO [,,,] 91864 --- [
> > main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 -
> > Shutdown completed. 2020-08-15 10:58:26.117  INFO [,,,] 91864 --- [
> > main] o.s.i.monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter   : Summary on shutdown:
> > bean 'auditProducer' 2020-08-15 10:58:26.117  INFO [,,,] 91864 --- [
> > main] o.s.i.monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter   : Summary on shutdown:
> > bean 'integrationErrorsConsumer' 2020-08-15 10:58:26.117  INFO [,,,]
> > 91864 --- [           main] o.s.i.monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter   :
> > Summary on shutdown: bean 'signalProducer' 2020-08-15 10:58:26.117
> > INFO [,,,] 91864 --- [           main]
> > o.s.i.monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter   : Summary on shutdown: bean
> > 'commandResults' 2020-08-15 10:58:26.118  INFO [,,,] 91864 --- [
> > main] o.s.i.monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter   : Summary on shutdown:
> > nullChannel 2020-08-15 10:58:26.118  INFO [,,,] 91864 --- [
> > main] o.s.i.monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter   : Summary on shutdown:
> > bean 'messageEvents' 2020-08-15 10:58:26.118  INFO [,,,] 91864 --- [
> > main] o.s.i.monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter   : Summary on shutdown:
> > bean 'signalConsumer' 2020-08-15 10:58:26.118  INFO [,,,] 91864 --- [
> > main] o.s.i.monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter   : Summary on shutdown:
> > bean 'asyncExecutorJobs' 2020-08-15 10:58:26.118  INFO [,,,] 91864 ---
> > [           main] o.s.i.monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter   : Summary
> > on shutdown: bean 'commandConsumer' 2020-08-15 10:58:26.118  INFO
> > [,,,] 91864 --- [           main]
> > o.s.i.monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter   : Summary on shutdown: bean
> > 'errorChannel' 2020-08-15 10:58:26.118  INFO [,,,] 91864 --- [
> > main] o.s.i.monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter   : Summary on shutdown:
> > bean 'integrationResultsConsumer' 2020-08-15 10:58:26.118  INFO [,,,]
> > 91864 --- [           main] o.s.i.monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter   :
> > Summary on shutdown:
> > org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.StreamListenerMessageHandler@4e9b4e98
> > 2020-08-15 10:58:26.118  INFO [,,,] 91864 --- [           main]
> > o.s.i.monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter   : Summary on shutdown:
> > org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.StreamListenerMessageHandler@6e3f108c
> > 2020-08-15 10:58:26.118  INFO [,,,] 91864 --- [           main]
> > o.s.i.monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter   : Summary on shutdown: bean
> > '_org.springframework.integration.errorLogger.handler' for component
> > '_org.springframework.integration.errorLogger' 2020-08-15 10:58:26.118
> > INFO [,,,] 91864 --- [           main]
> > o.s.i.monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter   : Summary on shutdown:
> > org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.StreamListenerMessageHandler@1eba2b8d
> > 2020-08-15 10:58:26.119  INFO [,,,] 91864 --- [           main]
> > o.s.i.monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter   : Summary on shutdown:
> > org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.StreamListenerMessageHandler@329b6556
> > 2020-08-15 10:58:26.121  INFO [,,,] 91864 --- [           main]
> > o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
> > 2020-08-15 10:58:26.144  INFO [,,,] 91864 --- [           main]
> > ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener :
>
> Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report
> re-run your application with 'debug' enabled. 2020-08-15 10:58:26.153
> ERROR [,,,] 91864 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication
> : Application run failed
>
> org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to
> start bean 'outputBindingLifecycle'; nested exception is
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A default binder has been
> requested, but there is no binder available   at
> org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:185)
> at
> org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:53)
> at
> org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:360)
> at
> org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:158)
> at
> org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:122)
> at
> org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.finishRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:162)
> at
> org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:554)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215)
> at
> org.activiti.cloud.runtime.RuntimeBundleApplication.main(RuntimeBundleApplication.java:27)
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A default binder has
> been requested, but there is no binder available  at
> org.springframework.util.Assert.notEmpty(Assert.java:549)     at
> org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.DefaultBinderFactory.doGetBinder(DefaultBinderFactory.java:157)
> at
> org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.DefaultBinderFactory.getBinder(DefaultBinderFactory.java:140)
> at
> org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindingService.getBinder(BindingService.java:379)
> at
> org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindingService.bindProducer(BindingService.java:268)
> at
> org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindingService.bindProducer(BindingService.java:291)
> at
> org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.AbstractBindableProxyFactory.createAndBindOutputs(AbstractBindableProxyFactory.java:136)
> at
> org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.OutputBindingLifecycle.doStartWithBindable(OutputBindingLifecycle.java:58)
> at
> java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedValues.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:608)
> at
> org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.AbstractBindingLifecycle.start(AbstractBindingLifecycle.java:57)
> at
> org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.OutputBindingLifecycle.start(OutputBindingLifecycle.java:34)
> at
> org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:182)
> ... 14 common frames omitted